# tinyScrollbar mousewheel on horizontal scroll only works for chrome

Tags: mousewheel, tinyscrollbar

I´m using tinyScrollbar for an horizontal scroll, but the mousewheel only works in chrome.

In Firefox (29.0.1) and in Internet Explorer (11), the mouse wheel is not working. I{m using windows 8.

You can check it out in the official web of the plugin (http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), in the horizontal scroll example with images.

Anybody else have this problem?